# Display dialog box only once and apply setting for the whole batch of images

Tags: photoshop-script

I wrote a simple jsx script, which displays a dialog box containing a list of checkboxes and 'Continue' button, which on click executes various commands depending on which items from the list were ticked.

As this script is supposed to be part of an Action Set, I created an action which just executes this script.

When I run the command File > Automate > Batch > The above action on a Folder or opened files, the dialog box shows for every image from the batch.

Is there any way to show this dialog box only once and apply all its settings to the whole batch?

Answer (score 0):

The better way to accomplish this is to add a folder picker to your dialog and modify the script to loop through all images in the folder (or open files, whatever your needs are) rather than attempt to run the script via an action.  If you really must have it in an action, the way I have done this before is to write a xml config file that the script will look for and apply the settings from there - skipping the dialog altogether.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply, it's one way to do it, but it would require deleting xml file, similar would be using app.putCustomOptions(); but this approach on the other hand requires restarting Photoshop after every batch.