# Photoshop scripting actions and batch

Tags: action, batch-processing, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

perhaps one can help me with some scripting snippets for:

A) supress/ignore open and save Dialog in Actions with PS-script

B) supress Color warnings while opening

C) toogle on/off a dialog box next to an action (inside a action with e.g. bluring dialog box, this should run with standard values) I know, I can toogle it on/off next to actions manual, but I will do this manual

D) remember all changes done in a actions dialog for first running of batch job and do all the same configs an other images. Otherwise the dialogs will shown up for every picture

Hope you can help me? I will programm some scripts for usage with other batch processors or pixelsplasher´s mockup smart replace.

This code I´ve found it works for simple scripting.

```
// ASSUMING DIALOGS ARE CURRENTLY SET TO NO/OFF
var savedDisplayDialogs = app.displayDialogs;

// CHANGE THE DIALOGS TO ON
//app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL;

// CHANGE THE DIALOGS TO OFF
app.displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;

//======================================

// MAIN SCRIPT CODE TO DO STUFF...
var act = "action"
var actset = "actionset"

app.doAction(act, actset);


//======================================

// RESTORE THE DIALOGS TO THEIR ORIGINAL SETTINGS
app.displayDialogs = savedDisplayDialogs;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer A is accessible from the action window itself:

[image: action dialog]

From left to right we have a tick (toggle action on/off), small file window (toggle dialog on/off) and the name of the action.
Uncheck the toggle dialog on/of on the action and before you run the script and it'll won't pop up any save open windows.

Comment: yes, thanks - I know this, but I´m searching a way to do this with scripting. And it should run temporary. I need an off and on script.

Comment: That's the real trick.  I think the answer lies [here](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/Photoshop/Application/batch.html?highlight=action) and [here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/how-to-run-photoshop-batch-via-javascript-vs-manually-selecting-all-attributes/m-p/12474797) Though I could not get it to work myself. (illegal argument)

Comment: Hmm, I found this old comment by Anna Forrest, but don´t know, how I can implement this in a batch process.:

[Display dialog box only once and apply setting for the whole batch of images][1]


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47003824/display-dialog-box-only-once-and-apply-setting-for-the-whole-batch-of-images/77771230#77771230

I´m working batch processing with:
- Image Processor Pro
- advanced Batch Processor (boogalooper github)
- codeandhastle batch+
- pixelsplasher smart replace batch processing with queue

Comment: Ghoul Fool: you´ve ask this also in adobe forum? Any news? https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop-ecosystem-discussions/running-an-action-via-scripting-with-options/m-p/14342854#M774250

Comment: Yup - I couldn't get it to work that was for my clarity - I was using a string instead of a file! But even though you can suppress open or save dialog of an action you still have to use the script to remove other dialog boxes.

Comment: OK, and how do you suppress dialogs inside an action? Specialy for filters with dialog prompts? Some code for me?

Comment: `// Switch off any dialog boxes
displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO; // OFF

// Switch the dialog boxes back to errors only
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ERROR; // ERROR

// Switch the dialog boxes back to normal
displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL; // ON`

Comment: It's a state thing, so it's best to set them at the start and end of a script.

Comment: This won't work. Dialogs from filter like blur will prompt. This was my first attemp.

Comment: We may be talking at cross-purposes. After much confusion, I don't think you can suppress action dialogues from a script. Feel free to prove me wrong, though.